# Is it possible to have a QWidget without a display?

Tags: windows, qt

I have a console-only win32 application (which can be launched as a windows service) where I want to create QWidget objects and interact with them.

These QWidget will not be rendered locally (because there is no display) but I need to access painting operations (to create screenshot of them for example) and I need to intercept mouse and keyboard operations.

The aim of the service is to provide a display of the widget to a remote application. So the image, mouse and keyboard are meant to be redirected over the network.

Is it possible to have QWidget objects in a console application? What is the preferred method to intercept painting, mouse and keyboard operations in that case?

If this is possible, is it still possible with QAxWidget objects?

Comment: How are keyboard and especially mouse operations supposed to work if the widget is not displayed anywhere on the screen?

Comment: The aim of the service is to provide a display of the widget to a remote application. So the image, mouse and keyboard are meant to be redirected over the network. Note: I'm looking at an alternative of existing remote display protocol like RDP for this very specific case.

Answer (score 1):

Have a peek at [Qt for embedded Linux.](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qt-embedded-crosscompiling.html). Qt is designed so you can do this, but it is non-trivial.

I do suspect you're not on the right track, though, if you have a console-mode service that needs a keyboard, mouse and a graphical UI. The need to interact with a user tells me that it should not be a service, and the need for a mouse suggests that it shouldn't be a console app either.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `QApplication` without a Gui using one of the [provided constructors](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qapplication.html#QApplication-2):

```
QApplication::QApplication(int&, char**, bool GuiEnabled)
```

In order to do GUI operations you'll still need a GUI available. For example, on Linux it will still require that X be running and available. I believe there are certain restrictions on what can and can't happen but can't find the blog post on http://labs.qt.nokia.com that provides details.

Comment: From the link: "On Windows and Mac OS, currently the window system is always initialized, regardless of the value of GUIenabled. This may change in future versions of Qt."

Answer (score 0):

At the moment i myself am trying to do something similar. The approach i have taken is creating subclass of QGraphicsScene and overriding QGraphicsScene::sceneChanged event. Then it goes as follows (pseudocode):

```
QApplication app;
MyGraphicsScene* mgs = new MyGraphicsScene();
MyWidget* mw = new MyWidget();
mgs->addWidget(mw);
```

Now each time change happens your sceneChanged will be invoked. There you can get snapshot of scene as QImage. In my case i move pixel data to texture and render it as overlay of my game:

```
void QEOverlay::sceneChanged(QList<QRectF> list)
{
    //loop through all screen areas that changed
    foreach(QRectF rect, list)
    {
        //generate a rectangle that is a while number, and fits withing the screen
        if(rect.x() < 0) rect.setX(0);
        if(rect.y() < 0) rect.setY(0);
        if(rect.right() > _width) rect.setRight(_width);
        if(rect.bottom() > _height) rect.setRight(_height);
        rect = QRectF(Round(rect.x()),Round(rect.y()),Round(rect.width()),Round(rect.height()));

        //Create an image, create a qpainter, fill the image with transparent color, and then render a part of the scene to it
        QImage image(rect.width(),rect.height(),QImage::Format_ARGB32);
        QPainter p(&image);
        image.fill(0);
        render(&p,image.rect(),rect);

        if(tex.lock())
        {
            for (u32 y = 0; y < image.height(); y++)
            {
                for (u32 x = 0; x < image.width(); x++)
                {
                    QRgb pix = image.pixel(x, y);
                    tex.color(x + rect.left(), y + rect.top(), Color(qRed(pix), qGreen(pix), qBlue(pix), qAlpha(pix)));
                }
            }
            tex.unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

There is issue with this approach. You still need to redirect keyboard and mouse input events to your subclass. That does not work out for me very well, there are certain issues like mouse click not focusing QLineEdit or elements in QWebView.

Comment: This is an interesting solution but, according to the documentation, it does not work with a QAxWidget object...